# What is the reason for exporting the private library dependencies of an Android project?

Tags: android, jit, dex

does exporting the libraries have something to do with JIT and compiling it into dex at runtime? I'm trying to make sure that my Android application has the smallest possible binary so that upgrades are not to big. Maybe someday Google will make upgrades partial instead of the whole APK.

Just now noticing these questions as the new ADT 22 has you manually export the "Android private libraries" now which used to be the libs folder and it would automatically export it anyway.

Comment: The "manually export" part is being worked on: https://groups.google.com/group/adt-dev/t/46bd455437da716f The changes that are there are to make things easier for Maven users.

Answer (score 0):

That reflects some of the changes that have been made in the build system. This is already how it used to be done in IntelliJ. It's all part of a bigger plan to make life easier with multiple builds and larger code-bases. I know it seems tedious now, but you'll see the advantages soon.

Comment: but is the exporting being required due to needing to JIT the code on an Android device? I know it was being done without us knowing before ADT 22.